# Queue node js-express Requests to handle 3rd party api request with a post limit

Tags: node.js, express, message-queue

I am using nodejs and express and have built a restful api. Certain api requests require my rest api to make post requests to a 3rd party api. This 3rd party api has a limit of 5 simultanoeus requests from the same domain.

```
 Code snippet from my rest api.

                if(acc_balance>req.body.amount){
                    return externalAPI.balance(req.body.currency.market_code) //call to 3rd party api
                }
                else{
                    throw new Error("Insufficient Funds");
                }
```

This means that if about 6+ users are accessing my rest api at the same time, some of those requests will return with erros cos the 3rd party api will return with a 503 Error. I am looking at a solution where i have a can queue requests and handle them one after the other other or in batches less than 5. Or some other solution that works for my case.

I have heard about RabbitMQ, not sure if that applies to my usecase.

Comment: Are you planning scale your service horisontaly (clusters, separate servers)?

Comment: I will be starting with a 2 server architecture - one for Api and the other for DB cos of limited funds

Comment: All three can we useful: bull - https://github.com/OptimalBits/bull
kue - https://github.com/Automattic/kue and RabbitMQ (but it is separate server)

Comment: which one do you recommend

Comment: I personally prefer Bull (built in Rate Limiter, Repeatable jobs and Global events)

Comment: Okay. Thanks a lot